# Getting vertex and normal indices to match when exporting mesh?

Tags: export, vertices, normals, obj

I am exporting a model as an obj. I want to store one normal per vertex, meanin I want the index of the normal and the vertex to be the same. I am getting this on my exported file:

```
f 3998//5668 20263//5669 8535//5670
```

I would expect something like:

```
f 3998//3998 20263//20263 8535//8535
```

Is there a way to instruct blender to have the normals and vertices ordered?

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't. Why do you need it?

Comment: I have a custom obj loader and I need them to be sorted this way for an experiment. I guess I will need to edit the loader, which I did not want to do..